# Test localhost app in Shopify

Tags: php, localhost, shopify

It's possible to test an app created on my localhost, on my Shopify test shop?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can install apps running on localhost into a Test Shop. Just make sure you've set your urls and callbacks correctly in your app and the app settings in your shopify partner account. The Shopify Test Shop is able to authenticate an app with OAuth running on localhost just fine.

The only thing you are not able to do while running an app on localhost is use WebHooks and ScriptTags. For this, you can use something like localtunnel: https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Mac, I wrote a small program to handle such a few years back called Localghost:

https://github.com/scotchi/Localghost/downloads

Basically it handles adding `/etc/hosts` entries and potentially proxying the connection to the specific port that your app is running on.  I wrote it when doing Shopify stuff, though there's nothing Shopify specific about it.  It does make it easier to handle the authentication and whatnot which returns the user to the app's "finalize" URL.